# Как удалить из строки в js всё кроме цифр и знаков / * - +

Tags: javascript

Пробовал:

```
let m = str.replace(/[^+-*/\d]/g, '')
```

но получал ошибку:

> ```
> > Invalid regular expression: /[^+-*/\d]/: Range out of order in
> > character class
> ```

Comment: минус поставь в начале или конце, в твоем случае - это знак диапазона

Comment: А разве не так 
let reg = [что надо]
let m = str.replace(имя_переменой_строки, $let)

Answer (score 0):

То есть вы хотите оставить только цифры и знаки которые вы перечислили? Тогда вот:

```js
let pattern = /[^0-9\/\*\-\+]+/g,
  log = (str) => console.log(str.replace(pattern, ''))

log('abc 123 = 456 def')
log('H3ll0_w0rld!')
log('2 * 2 = 2 + 2 = 4 / 2')
log('!@#$%^&*()_-+=')
```

P.S. если вы хотите сохранить пробелы тоже тогда используйте такой паттерн: `/[^0-9\/\*\-\+\s]+/g`

Comment: не работает `log('!@#$%^&*()_-+=')`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы реплейс не сделали, `log` просто сокращение от `console.log`. З.Ы. сейчас сделаю по-удобному :).

Comment: ......ааа) оке))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский проверяйте шарманку, теперь можно вводить строку и она сразу будет реплейсица :)